# Reliable Task Schedule

Tags: c#, schedule

Well... Please excuse me for positing such vague question but i am crashing my head because of it and i can't find a good logic to implement it or at least a good library that do such thing for me.

#### Situation

My application should be executing a lot of tasks in a different time intervals, some of which needs to be executed only after some conditions are satisfied or other methods completed and so on. [ think of it as a method dependency tree]... And i was wondering in such big projects like a Huge online game or such projects, how they organize their code in order to not crash or execute some methods in a wrong time or without satisfying it's conditions ?

#### Problem

The whole problem is that in my application i want the following specs

- Ability to schedule a method to run at a specified time.
- Ability to pause, cancel, stop, or even repeat a task.
- Ability to not execute a specific task until another task is finished
  so i can create some kind of Flow.
- Ability to create some kind of Flow in order to make sure that some
  methods will never execute until it's parent or procedure method have
  finished.
- All that in an organized, fluent yet powerful way.

Comment: all of these are possible with Quartz.NET

Comment: @SirwanAfifi :Quartz.NET have a very bad documentation i can't even try it's very basic functionalities... Even it's first lesson have a wrong code...

Comment: Its not that hard to create a state engine.

Comment: @Jay : I think state engine is just 1 part of the 5 points I have mentioned

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reactive Extensions (Rx.NET) might do the job! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx

Examples:

This examples schedules a task execution.

```
Console.WriteLine("Current time: {0}", DateTime.Now);

// Start event 30 seconds from now.
IObservable<long> observable = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

// Token for cancelation
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();

// Create task to execute.
Task task = new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("Action started at: {0}", DateTime.Now));

// Subscribe the obserable to the task on execution.
observable.Subscribe(x => task.Start(), source.Token);

// If you want to cancel the task do: 
//source.Cancel();

 Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
 Console.ReadKey();
```

Result:
[image]

Example 2:

Repeating a task every x seconds.

```
Console.WriteLine("Current time: {0}", DateTime.Now);

// Repeat every 2 seconds.
IObservable<long> observable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

// Token for cancelation
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();

// Create task to execute.
Action action = (() => Console.WriteLine("Action started at: {0}", DateTime.Now));

// Subscribe the obserable to the task on execution.
observable.Subscribe(x => { Task task = new Task(action);task.Start(); },source.Token);

// If you want to cancel the task do: 
//source.Cancel();
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Result:
[image]

Example task continue:

```
Console.WriteLine("Current time: {0}", DateTime.Now);

        // Repeat every 2 seconds.
        IObservable<long> observable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

        // Token for cancelation
        CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();

        // Create task to execute.
        Action action = (() => Console.WriteLine("Action started at: {0}", DateTime.Now));
        Action resumeAction = (() => Console.WriteLine("Second action started at {0}", DateTime.Now));

        // Subscribe the obserable to the task on execution.
        observable.Subscribe(x => { Task task = new Task(action); task.Start();
                                      task.ContinueWith(c => resumeAction());
        }, source.Token);

        // If you want to cancel the task do: 
        //source.Cancel();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The Reactive Extensions seem very good; However could you or anybody show me how could I use it for my particular needs ?

Comment: @ErricJManderin I've added 2 examples, how they help.

Comment: so what about if I wanted to resume or pause a task not just cancel it, or if I wanted to make sure that a specific task will never execute until another task has completed (Flow Like)

Comment: For task flow you can use ContinueWith, i shall add an example. Pause doesn't really exists. You can cancel the task or wait for a task to complete but not pause and resume it.

Comment: I am so sorry for so much requests but The most important thing is to achieve that continuity in a dynamic way so that I can add more jobs in the run time or remove some... so on

Comment: It is possible i think, if you remember the lastest task creation you can add the continuation task to it.

Comment: during the run time ?!

Comment: Can you give me a bit more information about the situation. When do you want to add a continuation task after an other? Why not schedule it normally.

Comment: The application will create some requests to collect data from website so some times you need to get a token code that is needed for the other task to work and without it the request will be invalid... also in some other situations I have to load some data during program initialization and this data is depending on the latest run time saved data.... it is a very big situation

Comment: So I want to centralize everything to run from a single Task Handler or manager that allows me to queue, run, schedule tasks with priorities and so on also have the abilities mentioned in the thread... Just for the sake of a more clean code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34319/discussion-between-martijn-van-put-and-erric-j-manderin)